# Como interagir o PHP com a interface Dialog do Shell Linux?

Tags: php, linux, shell, dialog

Como interagir o **php7-cli** com a interface **Dialog** do Shell Linux, exibindo valores das variáveis na tela?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Resolvi da seguinte forma:

**Pré-requisitos:** php5-cli ou superior.

**# apt-get install dialog**

dialog.php

```
<?php

$title   = 'Your title';
$message = 'Hello World!';

function dialog($args)
{
    $pipes  = array(NULL, NULL, NULL);
    $in     = fopen('php://stdin', 'r');
    $out    = fopen('php://stdout', 'w');
    $p      = proc_open('dialog ' . $args, array (0 => $in, 1 => $out, 2 => array ('pipe', 'w')), $pipes);
    $result = stream_get_contents($pipes[2]);

    fclose($pipes[2]);
    fclose($out);
    fclose($in);
    proc_close($p);

    return $result;
}

echo dialog("--no-shadow --title '" . $title . "' --msgbox '" . $message . "' 40 100");
```

Para executar:

**$ php dialog.php**

Resultado:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]